# Regex match multiple elements

Tags: regex

I have regex that I am trying to match to specific function parameters. I want to be able to style them a certain way in a language package.

Here is the text I am trying to match:

```
addFill(path:svgjs.Element, pattern:Pattern, docMaxSide:number) {
    pathFillId(path)
}
```

In this example, I want to match the words "path" "pattern" and "docMaxSide" from the parameters. I want to make sure it does NOT match the word "path" in the second line (where I am calling pathFillId).

Here is my current regex: `\(.*?(\w+):.*?\)`

Broken down:

`\(` Find open parens

`.*?` It may have stuff before it, but after the parens

`(\w+):` Capture a word before a colon

`.*?` There may be more stuff after the colon

`\)` Close parens

Right now, it will only match the first item, "path". But I need it to match all the words I mentioned above.

UPDATE: I should have been more specific. It should only match if it's a function parameter. For example, I don't want `path1` matched in the following: `var path1:string`. The difficulty is coming up with regex that matches items only between parens.

Comment: `(\w+):` Get the matched group from index 1. [DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/qO1vG7/1). What language are you using?

Comment: Braj, see my update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
\w+(?=:)
```

with the `g` modifier (the global modifier finds all elements and don't return on the first match)

Also see the **[example](http://regex101.com/r/eD3hP1/1)**

---

**UPDATE**

If you want only match the parameters in the parenthesis you can do this:

```
\w+(?=:[\w.]+\s*[,)])
```

Here is the **[example for this regex](http://regex101.com/r/fF0aN2/1)**

Comment: Super close! This works for the example I gave (I just looked up lookarounds, awesome), but it is too loose for all cases. It also matches 'path2' in `var path2:string = "hello"`, but I only want it to match parameters in functions. That's why I was including stuff about being inside parentheses. Any thoughts?

Comment: Awesome. Thank you so much. Now I just have to parse it to understand what's going on there. :)

Answer (score 0):

You problem is this part of your regex: `.*?`. So you specify that you want any character (`.`), that's correct. But then you must decide for one of `*` and `?` - `*` means `{0,}`, `?` means `{0,1}`.

If that doesn't help, you might test your regex with [regexe.com](http://regexe.com) or similar.